# How to simulate Media Streaming with Gatling

Tags: video-streaming, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

So in my simulation I need to replicate a page that contains a media player and streams a video also from the same backend.

Using the Get request from Gatling, it will download the entire video at once, instead of downloading only partial content like in a browser would happen.

Is there a way to control or pace download streams so it does not download the entire video at once but by partial content as it happens in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is called progressive download or pseudo-streaming. This is different from say streaming achieved via a streaming protocol like `HLS`.

Progressive download uses [HTTP range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests).

I haven't used [gatling](/questions/tagged/gatling) yet but I see it supports setting [headers](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/http_request/#headers) for HTTP requests. It should be possible to set the appropriate `Range` headers. Check the first link for examples.

If it works you'll see `206 Partial Content` responses.

Try something along the lines of:

```
http("Progressive download")
  .get("url")
  .header("Range", "bytes=0-1023")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my case !! Thank you very much.